# Setuping a triple integral when the bounds are given by more than one variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm having a problem in the following exercise:

Using an appropiate substituion, calculate:

$$\iiint\frac{\sin{(x+y-z)}}{x+2y+z}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

$1 \leq x+2y+z\leq 2$, $0 \leq x+y-z \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$

Since $z$ is given by the author, is fairly easy to setup for it:

$$\int_0^1\int\int\frac{\sin{(x+y-z)}}{x+2y+z}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

What about for $x$ and $y$? I know it may be easier if I plot the graph, but how to solve it without using this "shortcut"? Should I put $x$ in function of $y$ and $y$ in function of $z$? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Is the numerator $\sin(x+y-z)$ or is it $\sin(x+y)-z$ or is it $\sin(x)+y-z$?

Comment: @MarkViola fixed

Comment: If your numerator is meant to be $\sin(x+y-z)$ you will find the transformation $$(u,v,w)=(x+y-z,x+2y+z,z)$$ especially useful.

Comment: @MatthewPilling then instead of using $dxdy$ should I use $dudv$?

Comment: Have you learned about multivariate change of variables? Have you seen the Jacobian before, $\frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I had a lecture about it today